# Import commonJS, AMD, and ES6 modules at runtime with synchronous syntax

Tags: module, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I've been writing a lot of ES6 lately, using `import {variable} from 'ES6module'` syntax, and compiling the code in-browser with [traceur-compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler). I started looking at [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) since it seemed like it might allow me to use the same syntax to import AMD, commonJS, *and* ES6 modules.

Reading the documentation has started to confuse me though. I see a lot of asynchronous calls like `System.import('path/to/module').then(function(variable) { ... })` which I'm not used to for dependency importing.

I've read [Practical workflows for ES6 modules](http://guybedford.com/practical-workflows-for-es6-modules), which covers many different workflows, none of which involves importing an ES6 module *and* an AMD/commonjs module at runtime. I'm thinking something like this:

```
import {myObject} from 'my/es6/module';
import {_} from 'lib/underscore';
```

or if not that, than at least:

```
import {myObject} from 'my/es6/module';
var _ = require('lib/underscore');
```

Are either of these possible with systemjs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This use case is exactly what SystemJS is designed for.

You can write:

```
import {myObject} from 'my/es6/module';
import _ from 'lib/underscore';
```

The reason is because CommonJS, AMD and Global modules in SystemJS are treated as if they only export a `default` property, which corresponds to the default import syntax above.

Comment: Awesome! And I guess this also means that later calls to `import _ from 'lib/underscore';` will re-use the already imported module?

Comment: Yes exactly - module instances are shared.